# Improving Real-time Text Recognition Speed from Game Screen using OpenCV and Tesseract

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I am working on a real-time application to detect and recognize text from a specific game screen.I am capturing the game screen using mss, processing the captured image with OpenCV for enhancement, and finally recognizing text using Tesseract OCR.

However, my current implementation struggles to keep up with the game's pace, leading to many missed recognitions. I am seeking ways to optimize this process for better real-time performance.

I'm primarily focusing on two regions of the screen: a **`top_region`** which is the second most recent item and a **`bottom_region`** which is the most recent item. I capture these regions separately and process them for text recognition. After capturing and processing text from these regions, I check if the recognized text has changed from the previous frame to prevent redundant processing.

```
top_region = {'left': 12, 'top': 1128, 'width': 404, 'height': 23}
bottom_region = {'left': 12, 'top': 1152, 'width': 404, 'height': 23}

previous_texts = ["", ""]

with mss() as sct:
    while True:
        current_texts = []

        for idx, region in enumerate([top_region, bottom_region]):
            screenshot = sct.grab(region)
            screen = np.array(screenshot.pixels, dtype=np.uint8)[:, :, :3]
            screen_gray = cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

            # Binarization
            _, binary = cv2.threshold(screen_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)

            # Dilation
            kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
            dilated_img = cv2.dilate(binary, kernel, iterations=1)

            # Use Tesseract with additional configuration
            custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
            detected_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(dilated_img, config=custom_config)

            # Extract item name and amount using regex
            match = re.search(r'\[.*\](?: x(\d+))?', detected_text)
            if match:
                if match.group(1):
                    current_texts.append(match.group(0))
                else:
                    current_texts.append(match.group(0) + " x1")
            else:
                current_texts.append("")

            window_name = "Top Region" if idx == 0 else "Bottom Region"
            cv2.imshow(window_name, screen_gray)

        # Check for changes and process
        for i, text in enumerate(current_texts):
            if text != previous_texts[i]:
                # Check for Blood Wolf Mane
                if "[Blood Wolf Mane]" in text:
                    obtained_trash = int(re.search(r'\[Blood Wolf Mane\](?: x(\d+))?', text).group(1) or 1)
                    print(f"You have obtained [Blood Wolf Mane] x{obtained_trash}")
                    trashAmount += obtained_trash
                    print(obtained_trash);

        previous_texts = current_texts.copy()

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF in [ord('q'), ord('Q')]:
            print(trashAmount)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break
```

1. I've defined two regions (**`top_region`** and **`bottom_region`**) which represent the areas on the screen where relevant text can appear.
2. For each frame, I capture and process these regions separately to recognize the text.
3. I compare the recognized text with the text from the previous frame to identify any changes. If there's a change (like a new item being detected), I perform further processing on that text (e.g., tracking items).

For better clarity, here's a screenshot of the game's item box I'm trying to recognize text from:  [ItemDisplayBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhPoO.png)

My questions are:

1. Are there optimization strategies to make my current approach run faster?
2. Is there any alternative processing or recognition method better suited for real-time applications?
3. Are there more efficient ways to track the items than just tracking the most and second most recent item?

Any insights or suggestions would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.